# Notation S[F1:=T1,...,Fn:=Tn] in JSL

Tags: java, jsl

In section 4.5 of JLS (Parameterized Types) is mentioned the following notation:
`S[F1:=T1,...,Fn:=Tn]`.

I do not exactly unbderstand the meaning of this notation.

It is mentioned in the following paragraph:

> A generic type has type parameters F1,...,Fn with corresponding bounds
>   B1,...,Bn. Each type argument Ti of a parameterized type ranges over
>   all types that are subtypes of all types listed in the corresponding
>   bound. That is, for each bound type S in Bi, Ti is a subtype of
>   S[F1:=T1,...,Fn:=Tn] (§4.10).

The meaning of the statement above is clear.

But it is not clear for me why we have `[F1:=T1,...,Fn:=Tn]` after `S`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just looks wrong to me.

First: without the bracketed part, the sentence is a correct restating of the previous statement, and both match my understanding of the java language.

Second: the notation is wrong. §4.10 references the subtyping and supertyping notation <: and :>, but what is actually used is the replacement notation := (not actually defined as replacement notation in version 8 but was in version 7, and used as replacement in other sections of the document).

Finally: The previous version of the JSL had an even more nonsensical version of the same notation.

> [4.5. Parameterized Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5)
>
> A generic class or interface declaration C (§8.1.2, §9.1.2) with one
>   or more type parameters A1,...,An which have corresponding bounds
>   B1,...,Bn defines a set of parameterized types, one for each possible
>   invocation of the type parameter section.
>
> Each parameterized type in the set is of the form C where
>   each type argument Ti ranges over all types that are subtypes of all
>   types listed in the corresponding bound. That is, for each bound type
>   Si in Bi, Ti is a subtype of Si[F1:=T1,...,Fn:=Tn].

It has the same brackets, but this time does not even mention what F is prior to being used in the brackets.

It looks like the brackets were copied incorrectly when this section was rewritten between versions 6 and 7. Version 6 has the brackets but the simply mean the bounds check happens for each type parameter.

Comment: Also `Si` is indexed here (in JLS8 we have `S`).It looks like Si[F1:=T1,...,Fn:=Tn] is just Bi (i.e. the other form of notation of Bi)

Comment: Not exactly. Each type parameter (Fi) has a single bound (Bi), but each bound can themselves list several types (S). Of those types, only one can be a class, but a bound can include multiple interface types.

Comment: It looks clear now. If, for example, `Bi = MyClass & MyInterface` then `S[F1:=T1,...,Fn:=Tn]` shoud be either `MyClass` or `MyInterface`

Answer (score 0):

Here ia my thinking.

The notation `[F1:=T1,...,Fn:=Tn]` is a substitution of each type parameter `Fi` with concete type (or wildcard) `Ti, i=1,2,...n`.

Generic class can be thought as a function with `(n+1)` arguments `f(F1,F2,...,Fn, S)`, where `Fi` - is a type parameter and `S` belong to the following finite set `{B1,B2,...,Bn}`.
If we substitute `[F1:=T1,...,Fn:=Tn]` we get function with one argument:
`g(s)=f(T1,T2,...,Tn,S)`.

Considering that `[F1:=T1,...,Fn:=Tn]` is a substitution of `Fi` with `Ti, i=1,2,...,n`
we can introduce new notation:
`f(T1,T2,...,Tn,S)=h(S)[F1=T1,...,Fn=Tn]`.

Function `h(S)` should be linear: `h(S)=S`

Finally we have:
`f(T1,T2,...,Tn,S)=S[F1=T1,...,Fn=Tn]`.

Hence notion `S[F1=T1,...,Fn=Tn]` means: get one of upper bound `Bi` in fixed values `Fi=Ti`.